# Multiple DAGs getting created for a single manual run in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Whenever i trigger it manual i see two dags getting triggered, i thought only one will be triggered.

I am new to airflow not sure why such behaviour is happening.

Attaching the screnshot as well below the code.

```
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pendulum import timezone

local_tz = timezone("Asia/Dubai")
# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
    'owner': 'User',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 4, 15,tzinfo=local_tz)
}

dag = DAG('Helloworld',schedule_interval='0 17 * * *', default_args=default_args,catchup=False)


t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    bash_command='echo "Hello World from Task 1"',
    dag=dag)

t1
```

[image: Airflow UI]

Comment: Could you go to Browse -> Dag Runs and make a screenshot of this for your helloworld DAG

Answer (score 0):

By writing the schedule_interval=None it will work only one time and such behaviours are seen because airflow works on 24 hour window, till a 24 hour window is reached for a execution date dag will not be triggered.